# Convert Gaussian sum to integral?

Tags: integration, summation

Consider a sum of the following form:

$$S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{A-B(n-C)^2}$$

with constant $A,B,C>0$. Is there any way to convert this sum to an integral and evaluate via Gauss integral? Maybe it will be simpler to do if the summation starts at $-\infty$? Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: I've seen questions to this effect before though I don't know how to find them. As I recall the consensus was "no, but if you add up the first few terms of the series by hand, the remainder is very closely approximated by a Gaussian integral".

Comment: Your sum is related with the $\Theta(x)$ function and you may use Poisson summation formula to derive many nice properties, but there is no elementary integral that exactly equals your series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is not very clear why you do need this, the answer is:
in some cases intergal representations show up. Please consult the

1. *BERNDT, BRUCE C., and BYUNGCHAN KIM. “ASYMPTOTIC EXPANSIONS OF CERTAIN PARTIAL THETA FUNCTIONS.” Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society, vol. 139, no. 11, 2011, pp. 3779–3788. JSTOR, JSTOR, www.jstor.org/stable/41291944.* Freely available from http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2011-139-11/S0002-9939-2011-11062-1/S0002-9939-2011-11062-1.pdf
2. [Square Series Generating Function Transformations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.02803)
3. *Devroye, Luc, (2009), On exact simulation algorithms for some distributions related to Jacobi theta functions, Statistics & Probability Letters, 79, issue 21, p. 2251-2259.*